# How to convert a str like this format '2017-12-02 23:55:66.333+01:00' to datetime in python?

Tags: python, string, datetime, strptime

I need to convert a set of strings that is in this format "2017-12-02 23:55:66.333+01:00" to datetime.

I tried using this:

```
from datetime import datetime

date_time_str = '2017-12-02 23:55:66.333+01:00'

date_time_obj = datetime.strptime(date_time_str, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z')

print ("The date is", date_time_obj)
```

But i have this output:

```
>> ValueError: raise ValueError("time data %r does not match format %r" %
ValueError: time data '2017-12-02 23:55:66.333+01:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z'
```

How can i convert this date or this date_time_str is not valid?

Comment: How does a minute have a 66th second? Where are the milliseconds?

Comment: I have a file csv with this data : "2017-12-02 23:55:66.333+01:00", so i need to add a raise:except, the seconds are greater than 60

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I parse an ISO 8601-formatted date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127803/how-do-i-parse-an-iso-8601-formatted-date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems:

- your seconds are greater than 60
- you need to include the microseconds formatter

Thus to fix it,

```
from datetime import datetime
date_time_str = '2017-12-02 23:55:06.333+01:00'
date_time_obj = datetime.strptime(date_time_str, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z')
print("The date is", date_time_obj)
```

yields

```
The date is 2017-12-02 23:55:06.333000+01:00
```

You can catch the error caused by the seconds being too large and raise a helpful error message by

```
from datetime import datetime
date_time_str = '2017-12-02 23:55:06.333+01:00'
try:
    date_time_obj = datetime.strptime(date_time_str, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z')
except ValueError as ve:
    if "unconverted data remains" in ve.args[0]:
        raise ValueError("One of the values in the time string isn't meaninful")
    else:
        raise ve
print("The date is", date_time_obj)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, as I mentioned above , i have this string '2017-12-02 23:55:66.333+01:00' csv file, then i need to raise an exception because of the seconds are greater than 60, right?

Comment: Python will raise an error, but depending on your userbase, you may want to do a try:except and raise your own, more explanatory error

Comment: yes i will do a try:except. thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

here is what you want to do, missing stripping micorosecond and timezone section :

```
date_time_str = '2017-12-02 23:55:59.333+01:00'
date_time_obj = datetime.strptime(date_time_str, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z')
print ("The date is", date_time_obj)
```

output :

```
The date is 2017-12-02 23:55:59.333000+01:00
```

or simply using this in python 3.7+:

```
datetime.fromisoformat(date_time_str)
```

Comment: In Python 3.7 onwards, there's also `datetime.fromisoformat(date_time_str)`.

Comment: @zmike yes , there is. thank you for mentioning

Comment: @eshirvana, thank you! i have this string '2017-12-02 23:55:66.333+01:00' csv file, then i need to raise an exception because of seconds are greater than 60, right?

Comment: @AchrefMH yes , otherwise it is not a valid datetime value and actually Its more than 59 , 60 is also not acceptable